# How to select only json strings from a dynamic col in kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

The dynamic datatype column of my Table sometimes has values other than json in it,
But 'evaluate bag_unpack' command fails to run due to those.

Is there a way in which I can only select the properly formatted json strings from the col and send those to 'evaluate bag_unpack' while ignoring the rest of the garbage values.

Sample data:

```
{"message":"msg1","code":"1"}
<html><body>Server Down</body></html>
{"message":"msg2","code":2"}
{"message":"msg3","code":"3"}
```

Comment: Please add a data sample that represents your log structure accurately.

Comment: Does that represent a single log or four logs? If it is indeed a single log: Are there really new lines between the log parts and if so, does a line contain either a valid JSON document or non-JSON?

Comment: They are four different records of one table
Table
| project colname
| limit 4

Comment: Is `"code":2"` intentionally wrong?

Comment: yes, I am trying to show a sample of records from these i want to select the records that have valid json pairs only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bag_keys()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bagkeysfunction) is used in this case to figure out if the parsed log is a valid JSON or not

```
datatable(log_id:int, log:dynamic)
[
     1 ,'{"message":"msg1","code":"1"}'
    ,2 ,'<html><body>Server Down</body></html>'
    ,3 ,'{"message":"msg2","code":2"}'
    ,4 ,'{"message":"msg3","code":"3"}'
]
| extend parsed_log = todynamic(tostring(log))
| extend valid_json = iff(isnotempty(bag_keys(parsed_log)), parsed_log, dynamic(null))
| evaluate bag_unpack(valid_json)
```

| log_id | log | parsed_log | code | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"message":"msg1","code":"1"} | {"message":"msg1","code":"1"} | 1 | msg1 |
| 2 | Server Down | Server Down |  |  |
| 3 | {"message":"msg2","code":2"} | {"message":"msg2","code":2"} |  |  |
| 4 | {"message":"msg3","code":"3"} | {"message":"msg3","code":"3"} | 3 | msg3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WPTW7DIBBG95Z8hxGbgIQU2e7KcrPqDbqsKgubCaXhxzI4rdX27sVuUkcKbBh484ZPiph2Z5Aar1ota%200ih3Su5eyE1T3Ls5c8g2UVwHdfxGIIQiGpiQ2qIJz0Xi5VQX52fyAvE9i8RWsOTeflfHjG8YwjPPkP1%20zXm2a/Pl8bqntz%20W8uN/HDPVdtP6hW8DXPvgE/IzoJgxgDyjbFgUeI/hKJRh/iqJ1aMjN2w5%20F0bJ9D94lXh%20PVAfnI9ohzrQTqj3hHOgmZYzfjOBw9bvJmIs3GScREZbuyQ2iP9FtCPsF%20pouM34BAAA=)